# Excel Formula MMM to int

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Is there an excel formula that converts text months in short date format to their numeric value?

Example: Jan = 1, Feb = 2, ect.
I'm familiar with showing the numbers as text via =TEXT(1,"MMM") but not the other way around for these text values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`DATEVALUE`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx) function:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE("01/" & A1 & "/2012"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know DATEVALUE could be used to accept the text.
Googeling was providing bad results.

Comment: DATEVALUE will accept anything that Excel normally will parse as a date.

Comment: @Gimp Googling was prodiving bad results??? The first result in my search had `DATEVALUE`... twice.

Comment: I think my keywords were just failing me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this version

`=MONTH(1&A1)`

If A1 contains a text value like July or Jul then Excel will interpret 1July or 1Jul as a date, 1st July in the current year, and MONTH can give you the required month number. If A1 is empty then the formula returns 1 so you might want to add an IF function like this

`=IF(A1="","",MONTH(1&A1))`